# Why is the index position outputting data from other index's?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a list of values from two categories in a dataset called style 1 and style 2. However, when I input the code it creates a list that combines data from style 1 and style 2. The weird part is that it's grabbing these catchphrases from somewhere I'm not aware of? This is the dataset that I'm using and I cannot find the catchphrases within it: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jessicali9530/animal-crossing-new-horizons-nookplaza-dataset?select=villagers.csv

Here's my code:

```
style = []
for i in lines[1:]:
  vals = i.strip().split(',')
  style.append(vals[13])
  style.append(vals[14])
print(style)
```

Here's a small sample of what is being printed:

```
[' let it go. Then chase it down. What were you thinking?"', 'Active', 'Cool', 'Cool', 'Active', 'Simple', 'Simple', 'Elegant', 'Active', 'Active', 'Simple', 'Simple', 'Cute', 'Cute', 'Gorgeous', 'Elegant', ' water', ' and shelter!"',
```

As you can see there are these random catchphrases mixed within the style 1 and style 2 values. Not sure why or where it's coming from.

Comment: What are "style 1" and "style 2"? If you mean `vals[13]` and `vals[14]`, why do you expect them to be in separate lists if you append them to the same list? If you want them in separate lists, append them to separate lists

Comment: I don't want them to be in separate lists, I want them to be in the same list. The list is exactly how I want it, except for the random phrases interspersed throughout such as "let it go. then chase it down." and "and shelter!"

Comment: Simply splitting on commas only works if the CSV never contains commas in fields - that requires escaping or quoting to make the fields unambiguous.  I'm pretty sure that's what's going wrong here, but I can't access your file without creating an account, which I'm not willing to do.  Please add the first few lines of the file to your question.  (If that is the problem, the solution is to use the built-in `csv` module, or something like it that knows how to handle quoting.)

Answer (score -2):

Some lines must contain commas *inside* a csv field.  Usually in csv processing this is handled by putting double quotes around each field, like this:

```
Hero,Catchphrase,Sidekick
"Lone Ranger","Hi Ho, Silver!","Tonto"
"Superman","Up, Up, and Away!","Lois Lane"
```

You see that there are commas *inside* the catchphrase column.  Since they are inside the quotes, standard csv processing will handle it correctly.

However, it looks like you are not using standard csv processing.  You're just treating each csv data line as a standard string.  If you were to do the same with this sample data, the first line will split into four fields, and the second line into five.

Here's a short example of the right way to do it:

```
import csv
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # row[13] and row[14] are handled correctly
```

Comment: So how should I format my code? I'm not sure how to do it the standard way.

Comment: @FJFJFJJJ Use the built-in python `csv` module to read and write csv files, instead of treating it like a plain text file.